# Append an \item to nested enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate

I would like to append an `\item` to *nested* enumerate environments. The following example almost does what I want, but it also appends an `\item` to non-nested enumerates:

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtEndEnvironment{enumerate}{\item None of the above.}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 2 + 2 =
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \item 2
  \item 3
  \item 4
  \end{enumerate}
\item 2 - 2 + 5 =
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item 1
  \item 2
  \item 3
  \item 4
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

That is, it (understandably) creates in the output "3. None of the above", which I do not want.

I do not want a solution that relies on enumitem. And I do not want a solution that defines a new environment (unless the solution subsequently overwrites `enumerate`) because I want to use `\begin{enumerate}`, `\end{enumerate}`.

Comment: `\AtEndEnvironment{enumerate}{\ifnum \@listdepth>1 \item None of the above.\fi}`

Comment: I don't suppose `\newcommand{\nota}{\item None of the above.}` is automatic enough for you.  (https://libquotes.com/john-brunner/quote/lbo0y0x)

Comment: @JohnKormylo Nice quote :). Indeed that's not automatic enough.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer tested and works great. Thank you! Can you copy/paste your comment as an answer? I changed it slightly for my use case to `\ifnum \@listdepth=2` so that only the first level of nesting gets the extra item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nesting depth of a list is stored in `\@listdepth` so you can test for it:

```
\AtEndEnvironment{enumerate}{\ifnum \@listdepth>1 \item None of the above.\fi}
```